# Git make sub repo from private repo

Tags: git, gitlab

I have a private repo in GitLab, I want to create a sub repo from main repo and give it to another team to work on, but I don't want them to have access to all the files there, so there needs to be a selection of files and folders that they have access to.

I've already looked up in submodules in git, but it's not really what I'm looking for.

Also when their work is done, I want to merge their repo to the main one.

What can I do?

Comment: This is possible, but it's going to be a lot of work to keep the two in sync and I'm not aware of any tools to do so.  Submodules are definitely the better option.

Comment: [Subtree](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/git-subtree) would also be a possible solution to your problem description.

Comment: This [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77962008/7915017) may helps.