# git submodule add private repo in private repo

Tags: git-submodules, private-repository

People [ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71178373/importing-private-repo-to-other-private-repo-git) and [ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10628574/problems-with-git-submodules-when-submodules-are-private-github-repos) how `git submodule add` in case where both repos are private?

Comment: Okay, so why do you need to ask the same question just to answer it?

Comment: I make good step by step example!

Comment: Yes, your answer is perfect but it would be the same if you posted it to an existing question instead of duplicating the question just to post your answer.

Comment: Doesn't it occur to you that you can effectively double your chances of getting your answer noted an upvoted if you posted it tailored to those two existing questions?

Comment: It looks like that people ask the same questions, but may be not. And also I dislike their question sentence (not clear). And old topics already have accepted answers (it is important to me). So I decide to make new topic, but add links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my example.

Let's generate key pairs for every private repo.

```
user@linux:~/.ssh$ cd $HOME/.ssh && ssh-keygen -t ed25519 -f "myMother_key" -N "" -C "myKeyForGitHubMother" <<< $'\ny' >/dev/null 2>&1
user@linux:~/.ssh$ cd $HOME/.ssh && ssh-keygen -t ed25519 -f "myBaby_key" -N "" -C "myKeyForGitHubBaby" <<< $'\ny' >/dev/null 2>&1
```

Via FireFox I open `github.com` and manually add `myMother_key.pub` file to `git@github.com:AndreiCherniaev/mother.git` repo (Allow write access checkbox yes) and `myBaby_key.pub` to `git@github.com:AndreiCherniaev/baby.git` (Allow write access checkbox yes)

I am [Using multiple repositories on one server](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/managing-deploy-keys#using-multiple-repositories-on-one-server) So my `~/.ssh/config` file contains

```
Host babysubdomain.github.com
  HostName github.com
  User git
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/myBaby_key
  IdentitiesOnly yes

Host mothersubdomain.github.com
  HostName github.com
  User git
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/myMother_key
  IdentitiesOnly yes
```

Where `babysubdomain.` `mothersubdomain.` is any text.

Let's clone baby repo.

```
user@linux:~$ git clone git@babysubdomain.github.com:AndreiCherniaev/baby.git
```

Just for fun let's add any public repo as submodule for baby. In my example I will use [Buildroot](https://buildroot.org/) project

```
user@linux:~$ cd baby
user@linux:~/baby$ git submodule add -b master https://github.com/buildroot/buildroot myBuildroot/buildroot
user@linux:~/baby$ git commit -m "add submodule myBuildroot/buildroot/ to baby"
user@linux:~/baby$ git push
```

Let's back to `Download/` and clone `mother` repo

```
user@linux:~/baby$ cd ..
user@linux:~$ git clone git@mothersubdomain.github.com:AndreiCherniaev/mother.git
user@linux:~$ cd mother
```

Let's add submodule to `mother` repo

```
user@linux:~$ cd mother/
user@linux:~/mother$ git submodule add -b main git@babysubdomain.github.com:AndreiCherniaev/baby.git
user@linux:~/mother$ git commit -m "add submodule baby to mother"
user@linux:~/mother$ git push
```

Now let's remove local copy of mother/ from your PC

```
user@linux:~/mother$ cd ..
user@linux:~$ rm -Rf mother/
```

Let's clone mother with baby with buildroot

```
git clone --recurse-submodules -j8 git@mothersubdomain.github.com:AndreiCherniaev/mother.git
```

Now we have repo mother with submodule baby with submodule myBuildroot/buildroot/

Thanks [Gubatron](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26507643/7915017) and [link](https://gist.github.com/gubatron/d96594d982c5043be6d4?permalink_comment_id=4539050#gistcomment-4539050). Tested on Ubuntu 22.